# How to avoid abuse of image-preview traffic?

Tags: php, image, preview

Facebook and Google+ has both a great feature: Image preview. When you write in URL of your web, images are taken and you can select between them - it's done with proxy script.

My question is - Is there a way to reproduce same behavior BUT prevent users to insert links to big files which are expected to be HTML files? Proxy script could look like this

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents($_GET['url']); //problem is on this line - When $_GET['url'] is url to 5GB file, it will try to download it - How could I prevent it?
$images = preg_match_all('~img src="(.*?)"~', $contents, $images);
if ($images){
    echo json_encode($images[1]);
else 
    die('[]');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue a `HEAD` request, which is basically a `GET` but does not transfer any of the file's contents. You can then extract the `Content-length` header and see how much data you WOULD be fetching had it been a GET.

However, note that nothing prevents a malicious user from serving up two different sets of data - "this image is 10k" via 'head', and then serving up a terabyte of data via 'get'. It'd waste their bandwidth as well as yours, but it is possible.

Comment: so do you think even Facebook has these problems, sometimes?

Comment: Facebook wouldn't use as simplistic tool as file_get_contents. They'd have their own solution which might do a get, but terminates the transfer after 100k or 1meg or whatever. As well, given the size of FB, it'd be highly unlikely a malicious user could swamp FB's bandwidth by serving up a terabyte-sized .jpg. At most they'd tie up one single server in FB's huge server farm.

Comment: I know they wouldn't, it was just example

Answer (score 3):

Use [cURL](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fbook.curl.php&rct=j&q=php%20curl&ei=4lBJTsLOGuXj0QG4rendBw&usg=AFQjCNHgC-iCkFg5s9Dl77qCie4t94TXlw&sig2=Fde2VgGBsZrDCYHV9bqyvQ&cad=rja) (or some facsimile) and grab a `HEAD` request first. This will provide [`Content-Length`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) headers that will tell you the end result of the URL (size in bytes) before trying to retrieve the entire contents.

Comment: However, this is not fool proof as you can easily spoof headers. It's very easy with php `header()`

Comment: Everything on the web is 'cheatable'.

Comment: Cheatable? Yes. Foolproof? Nothing on the web is. However, you're working within the protocol to get the "most accurate" answer possible (with least amount of effort). You could, also, use a "hard" fopen/fread/close and read until a threshold byte limit is reached (cease when you're out of your comfort zone of read bytes).

Answer (score 2):

[`string file_get_contents ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context [, int $offset = -1 [, int $maxlen ]]]] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Actually, there is an optional parameter in `file_get_contents` for the max length to read.

> maxlen Maximum length of data read. The default is to read until end
>   of file is reached. Note that this parameter is applied to the stream
>   processed by the filters.

Comment: so this does restrict to send/get more than 32M even via CURL ?

Comment: @genesis Disregard my previous response. I see now that you can specify to `file_get_contents` a maximum length to read